# ActiveX issue in PowerPoint 

Tags: c#, activex, powerpoint

We have written an ActiveX control using C# to use it in Microsoft PowerPoint. The control has following Title: 'Test Viewer'. When I place the control in PowerPoint in edit mode, I see the title in control. But when I print the slide, it show me a big "X" in the print output. Print preview looks proper. I tried using 'PrintDocument' and 'PrintPageEventHandler' in the code but that doesn't seem to hit when printing the slide in PowerPoint edit mode. Can someone throw pointers how to achieve this? Is the data in control need to be communicated in some format?